# Let a and b be $3D$ vectors. Which of the following expressions make sense?

Tags: vectors

Let $a$ and $b$ be $3D$ vectors. Which of the following expressions make sense?

$A.
(a\cdot b)+a$

$ B.
(a\times b)+a$

$ C.
(a\times b)\cdot a$

$ D.
(a\times b)\times a$

Comment: BCD are valid. A is invalid. Do you understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little vector intuition:
A vector is a quantity that has direction and magnitude. In other words, it points somewhere and has a certain length. Vectors in 3d $(\mathbb{R}^3)$ are represented by an $x$, $y$, and $z$ coordinate, usually like follows: $\big<x, y, z\big>$.
There are two ways to multiply two vectors together. One way is the dot product, $a\cdot b$. This operation tells you to multiply the identical components of the two vectors together, and sum them. So, if you have these two vectors:
$$a=\big<1, 3, 0\big>\\b=\big<4, -1, 2\big>$$
$$a\cdot b=(1)(4)+(3)(-1)+(0)(2)=1$$
The dot product always gives you a scalar value, which is just a number (no direction).
The other way of multiplying vectors is by taking the cross product $(a\times b)$. You do this by taking the three by three determinant of the two vectors. I'm not going to explain how in this answer, because it'd take a while, but you can go [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CrossProduct.aspx) for a good explanation.
The point is, $a\times b$ gives you a vector (of form $(x, y, z)$), not a scalar.
So now to your question:
You cannot combine different types of values; imagine trying to add a number to a point $(x, y)$ - i.e. what is $(3, 2) + 4$? You can't do it. It's the same here. You cannot add scalars and vectors.
So in letter A, $a\cdot b$ gives you a scalar; $a$ itself is a vector. You cannot add scalars and vectors, therefore this is not really valid.

Comment: I see, that's all the information I'm given on this coursework, I can tick as many answers as I want. Thank you for explaining the dot product and scalar

Comment: Ok, in that case I would say that adding a vector quantity and a scalar quantity doesn't make sense (it's adding two different types of values). Does that help?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly all the answers that have cross products can not be correct as it gives another vector. That leaves B and D, by adding the scalar quantity not making sense do you mean that the answer has to be D? Sorry if I'm completely wrong, I'm just starting with vectors

Comment: No problem. I'll edit my answer now that I know the level you're at (which is why it's a good idea to include your level of understanding in your original question :) )

Comment: I would greatly appreciate that

Comment: Got it, thank you for spending your time on my question, I really get the rules of vectors now. I now know how to answer a similar question this to.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these rules:

1. `(scalar)(vector) = (vector)`
2. `(vector)+(vector) = (vector)`
3. `(vector)·(vector) = (scalar)`
4. `(vector)×(vector) = (vector)`

and `(scalar)+(vector)` is invalid.